# How can I expand the radius of a light bloom?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graphics, effects

I am writing a software filter object and trying to implement a light bloom effect.  I'm using a simple, two pass convolution approach which works fine except that the effect radius is tiny and I can't seem to control the radius.  I've played with larger box filters and adjusted the weights of the various pixels, but none of that seems to have any effect.  The effect seems to have a maximum size (which is not very big) and then all changes to the parameters just serve to make it smaller.

I'd like to be able to create a light bloom with an arbitrary radius.  After a LOT of experimentation and searching online, I'm starting to wonder if this just can't be done.  I've been thinking about alternate approaches--plasmas, gradients, and various seeding schemes--but I'd like to hound this path into the ground first.  Does anyone out there know how to create an arbitrarily sized light bloom (in software)?

The javascript is as follows (this operates on an HTML5 canvas; I can add comments to the code if needed):

```
// the kernel functions are called via Array.map on this.backBuffer.data, a canvas surface color array
this.kernelFirstPass = function(val, index, array)
{
    if(index<pitch || index>=array.length-pitch || index%pitch<4 || index%pitch>pitch-5 || index%4==3)
        return;
    var c = 1,
        l1 = 1,
        l2 = 1,
        l3 = 1,
        r1 = 1,
        r2 = 1,
        r3 = 1;
    var avg =
    (
        c*this.frontBuffer.data[index]+
        l1*this.frontBuffer.data[index-4]+
        l2*this.frontBuffer.data[index-8]+
        l3*this.frontBuffer.data[index-12]+
        l1*this.frontBuffer.data[index+4]+
        l2*this.frontBuffer.data[index+8]+
        l3*this.frontBuffer.data[index+12]
    )/(c+l1+l2+l3+l1+l2+l3);
    //this.frontBuffer.data[index] = avg;
    array[index] = avg;
}
this.kernelSecondPass = function(val, index, array)
{
    if(index<pitch || index>=array.length-pitch || index%pitch<4 || index%pitch>=pitch-4 || index%4==3)
        return;
    var c = 1,
        l1 = 1,
        l2 = 1,
        l3 = 1,
        r1 = 1,
        r2 = 1,
        r3 = 1;
    var avg =
    (
        c*array[index]+
        l1*array[index-pitch]+
        l2*array[index-(pitch*2)]+
        l3*array[index-(pitch*3)]+
        l1*array[index+pitch]+
        l2*array[index+(pitch*2)]+
        l3*array[index+(pitch*3)]
    )/(c+l1+l2+l3+l1+l2+l3);
    array[index] = avg;
}
```

---

Perhaps an important point that I missed in my original question was to explain that I'm not trying to simulate any real or particular phenomenon (and it probably doesn't help that I call it a "light" bloom).  It could be that, when dealing with real light phenomenon, in order to have a penumbra with arbitrary radius you need a source (ie. "completely saturated area") with arbitrary radius.  If that were in fact the way a real light bloom behaved, then Jim's and tskuzzy's explanations would seem like reasonable approaches to simulating that.  Regardless, that's not what I'm trying to accomplish.  I want to control the radius of the "gradient" portion of the bloom independently from the size/intensity/etc. of the source.  I'd like to be able to set a single, white (max value) pixel in the center of the screen and have the bloom grow out as far as I want it, to the edges of the screen or beyond if I feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve a good bloom effect, you should be using [high-dynamic range rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_dynamic_range_rendering) . Otherwise, your whites will not be bright enough.

The reason for this is that pixel brightnesses are typically represented from the range [0,1]. Thus the maximum brightness is clamped to 1. However in a real world situation, there isn't really a maximum. And although really bright lights are all perceived as a "1", the visual side-effects like bloom are not the same.

So what you have to do is allow for really bright areas to exceed the maximum brightness, at least for the bloom convolution. Then when you do the rendering, clamp the values as needed.

Once you have that done, you should be able to increase the bloom radius simply by increasing the size of the [Airy disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk) used in the convolution.

Comment: _Does anyone out there know how to create an arbitrarily **sized** light bloom **(in software)**._    
First, I am writing this in software; I know there are very nice, elegant solutions in hardware, but that's not what I'm doing.

Second, it's not the brightness that I'm asking about, it's the radius of the effect.  It's precisely because the range is limited that I want to control the fall off to expand the radius of the bloom.

Answer (score 0):

The simple summary of tskuzzy's answer is: use a floating-point buffer to store the pre-bloom image, and either convolve into a second floationg-point buffer (whence you saturate the pixels back into integer format) or saturate on the fly to convert each output pixel back to integer before storing it directly in an integer output buffer.

The Airy convolution must be done with headroom (i.e. in either fixed-point or floating-point, and these days the former isn't usually worth the hassle with fast FPUs so common) so that brighter spots in the image will bleed correspondingly more over their neighbouring areas.

Note: on-the-fly saturation for colour isn't as simple as individually clipping the channels - if you do that, you might end up with hue distortion and contours around the spots that clip.

Comment: I'm not positive that I've understood your answer (if you think that I've misunderstood, perhaps a specific example may help), but it sounds like what both you and tskuzzy are suggesting will create an area of max intensity with arbitrary radius, surrounded by a "penumbra" with the same radius as before. Using this metaphor, I'm looking for arbitrary control over the radius of the "penumbra". Also, you could think of the effect as "falloff" that is a function of distance from the source.  Currently, this falloff has a high slope and I'm wanting to have arbitrary control over the slope.